# How should I remove a large number of stones in my plot of land?

Tags: soil, rocks

I have a plot that I would like to use to make an orchard. The problem is that there are too many stones. I was looking for solutions and the only thing I found is a stone removing machine, which looks like [this](http://www.interempresas.net/FotosArtProductos/P1554.jpg), but I think it's too expensive for a small orchard.

What's the best solution?

Comment: cleanser to remove stones? Can you explain that a bit more?

Comment: Sorry, it's a wrong translation (thanks google translate) I mean this machine: http://www.interempresas.net/FotosArtProductos/P1554.jpg

Comment: The traditional solution is hired hands. That said, for an orchard, I assume you don't need the entire field cleared...just the spots for the trees, right?

Comment: Thats true, I just need small areas, but if there is a better solution than doing it manually it would be very helpfull

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a number of options depending on the size and depth of your stones and the area to be cleaned:

If the area to be cleaned is small, you could manually do it with a pick and shovel. If the stones are really big you may need a jackhammer.

But it sounds like you have a commercial size orchard, so I'll give you the options for large machine clearing.

If they are reasonably small and shallow, you could use something like a beach cleaner:
[image: Small Beach Comber]
There are small ones like above.

[image: Large Beach Comber]
And there are large, tractor pulled varities

If the stones are large, you may need a backhoe

[image: Back hoe]

You're best option is to grab the whitepages and find either a rental company in your area or a contractor to do it for you. They will have the right equipment and advice for an undertaking of this size.

Answer (score 3):

There is a solution, but if it's only a small area, it'll probably not be much good to you because it's a large piece of plant. There is a machine which does this used by landscapers on large areas - it's called the 612W Trommel, which is a self contained, portable, deisel powered piece of screening plant. It'll sort topsoil from stones and debris - you put the soil in one end and it spits out two separate piles, one of soil and the other of debris, from its conveyor belt.

Comment: It's something like that what I'm looking for, but not big.

Comment: Unfortunately, so far as I'm aware, there is no small version of this piece of machinery. The nature of the job it does dictates its size.